# Apache Camel - Hawtio - Error when trying to render route diagram

Tags: apache-camel, hawtio

I'm having problems
Hawtio: hawtio-app-1.4.45.jar
Camel: 1.14.1

Getting the following error when trying to render the route diagram or when entering source. I have 2 projects with the similar setup but can't understand why one of the projects can't render it.

```
[Core] Operation unknown failed due to: javax.management.RuntimeErrorException : Error occurred in RequiredModelMBean while trying to invoke operation dumpRoutesAsXml
```

I'm posting this post only for documenting the issue, in case someone else get stuck with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did find out when looking at the dependencies, there were actually a diff,

```
.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.11\jaxb-impl-2.2.11.jar (working)
.m2\repository\com\sun\xml\bind\jaxb-impl\2.2.7\jaxb-impl-2.2.7.jar (not working)
```

Then I realised the project which didn't work were using Camel 2.14.1 and the one which was working 2.15.1, so in case you find this problem, upgrade the Camel version and it will probably work